# Node 16.13.2 with NPM 8.19.4 throwing dependency error

Tags: npm

After upgrading Node from version 14 to 16.13.2, `npm install`  throws dependency error.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gallery@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: prettier@1.19.1
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier
npm ERR!   dev prettier@"^1.19.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer prettier@">=2.0.0" from pretty-quick@3.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/pretty-quick
npm ERR!   pretty-quick@"^3.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried downgrading NPM to version 6.12.1 and it worked.

But is it a correct way to to have Node 16.13.2 and NPM 6.12.1?

Comment: Why don't you resolve the conflict?

Comment: I tried to upgrade the packages that its throwing error but still unable to do npm install.